# Получить время работы процеса

Tags: winapi, c++builder, c++

Как получить время работы процеса в **секундах**, используя функцию `GetProcessTimes()`?
А также время работы потока с помощью аналогичной функции `GetThreadTimes()`?

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот **[официальный хелп](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx)** по этому поводу. **Сигнатура функции:**

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProcessTimes(
  _In_   HANDLE hProcess,
  _Out_  LPFILETIME lpCreationTime,
  _Out_  LPFILETIME lpExitTime,
  _Out_  LPFILETIME lpKernelTime,
  _Out_  LPFILETIME lpUserTime
);
```

**Я лишь прокомментирую, что здесь требуется.**

```
1) hProcess - собственно, сам дескриптор, указывающий на открытый хэндл процесса.
2-5) Параметры типа **[FILETIME][2]**, передаваемые по ссылке.  В них функция запишет время создания процесса, время выходного времени, время, которое процесс уже висит в режиме ядра и время, которое процесс висит в режиме пользователя.
```

**Функция возвращает TRUE при удаче и FALSE при фейле.**

**И пример, как всегда:**

```
HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
FILETIME ft[4];
GetProcessTimes(hProcess,&ft[0],&ft[1],&ft[2],&ft[3]);
```

C **[GetThreadTimes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237(v=vs.85).aspx)** все обстоит точно так же, разве что первый параметр - дескриптор, указывающий на открытый хэндл потока.

Answer (score 1):

Я уже сам нашел! Спасибо!

```
HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
FILETIME ft[4];
SYSTEMTIME tm[4];

GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ft[0], &ft[1], &ft[2], &ft[3]);

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft[i], &tm[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `facepalm.jpg`